# how to apply xsl styles to an embedded xml inside html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have a html file embedded xml tags inside, here i am trying to apply xslt styles are written in another separate file (somefile.xsl) importing with javascript, i am successful applying styles with external xslt file importing with javascript but it is working only in internet explorer , other browsers failed to apply styles.. bellow is my html code please look at my code. where i am doing wrong here ? Except IE no other browser seem  working with these technique.

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Sample XML with XSL</TITLE>
        <xml id="elx">
            <hello-world>  
            <greeter>An XSLT Programmer</greeter>   
            <greeting>Hello, World! </greeting>
           </hello-world>
       </xml>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <SCRIPT language = "javascript">
   if(window.ActiveXObject)
   {
    //IE
         alert("hi");
         var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
         xslDoc.async = false;
         xslDoc.load("helloworld.xsl");
         document.write(elx.transformNode(xslDoc));
 }
 else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
  //For Other Browsers

          xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
          xsltProcessor.importStylesheet("helloworld.xsl");
          result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(elx);
          // here 'elx' is id of embedded xml in header.
          document.write(result);
 }

  </SCRIPT>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

and here is my xsl ( helloworld.xsl ) file which i am trying to import with javascript and adding styles to embedded xml inside html file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.1" encoding="iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:template match="/hello-world">
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>
            </TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <H1>
                <xsl:value-of select="greeting"/>
            </H1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="greeter"/>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
</xsl:template>
```

within my html file i get only id of that xml file, by using that xml id i need to apply styles using javascript. hope you understand my issue and please solve this as soon as possible.

Comment: The problem may be because the xml data island was only ever a microsoft supported feature in HTML, and probably not recognised by other browsers. In fact, Microsoft are no longer going to support it in IE10 and above (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801224(v=vs.85).aspx). I think the solution will have to be to have your XML in a separate file rather than embedded in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

importStylesheet needs object(not url to file), you can get it from domParser

```
var domParser = new DOMParser();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet( domParser.parseFromString(some_text_value, "text/xml") );
```

Full lazy solution for Firefox/Chorme like following code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script id="elx" type="text/xml">
    <hello-world>  
        <greeter>An XSLT Programmer</greeter>   
        <greeting>Hello, World! </greeting>
   </hello-world>
</script>
<script id="stlsh" type="text/xml">
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.1" encoding="iso-8859-1" />
    <xsl:template match="/hello-world">
        <HTML>
            <BODY>
                <H1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="greeting"/>
                </H1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="greeter"/>
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT language = "javascript">
    var domParser = new DOMParser();
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet( domParser.parseFromString(stlsh.innerHTML, "text/xml") );
    var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument( domParser.parseFromString(elx.innerHTML, "text/xml") );

    document.write(result.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you will want use external files, you need to change stlsh.innerHTML/elx.innerHTML to XMLHttpRequest with responseText and put it to domParser.

Or get XMLHttpRequest responseXML.documentElement - may be, domParser doesn't need

Answer (score 0):

well for sure the go to XSL tutorial is W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

but in your cause I think the if-statement around your "other browser" is the issue that is suspect.

```
<yourCode>
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
</yourCode>
```

can you add an alert or a console log into that If statement to check? also why do you have a second if statement at all? if you have "IE code" and "non IE" code why not just put it in an else?

NOTE: have not tried your code, its thanksgiving night and im a bit tired but just a few thoughts

Comment: Yes in else block 'alert()' is working but styles are not applying to the xml id 'elx' with javascript command -> result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(elx); i dont know whats wrong in this line of code. i need a solution if anybody found in any otherway..